# Show the total sales by year. Display the year and the total sales. Sort by year

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following question to answer for an assignment. It's the last question I have and I'm totally lost. The question is:

Show the total sales by year. Display the year and the total sales. Sort by year.

An image of the ERD I have to go on is linked below:

[ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2l6aV.jpg)

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT SalesOrder.OrderDate AS year,
SUM(SalesOrder.OrderTotal) AS OrderTotal
FROM
SalesOrder
GROUP BY SalesOrder.OrderDate;
```

Which prints out the following:

```
year                    OrderTotal
2/3/2011 5:37:11 PM     372.0000
3/17/2011 3:33:00 PM    268.0000
3/19/2011 10:33:00 AM   21782.5000
3/7/2012 12:00:00 AM    871.5300
4/6/2012 12:00:00 AM    1010.0000
4/9/2012 6:47:39 PM     540.9000
4/10/2012 9:40:00 PM    22.8300
5/7/2013 11:42:37 AM    11.8500
5/7/2013 7:36:05 PM     35.6000
```

This should be my result:

```
year OrderTotal
2011 22422.5000
2012 2445.2600
2013 47.4500
```

How do I get the rows to only display one year, the properly added total per year, and display only the year?

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Have you looked at the `year` function? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year (assuming you are using the MySQL database engine)

Comment: Hi Brian. I just put that in per your instruction and it's definitely a step in the right direction. I just need the years to only show one total. As of right now with just the YEAR function I'm getting multiple OrderTotals per year. I need it to just print out one order total per year like the final result above.

Comment: So you want to group by the year of that date, ie.  `group by year(SalesOrder.OrderDate)`

Comment: THAT'S IT! You're awesome. Thank you so much for the help. Do you think you could explain to a coding newbie specifically why the year needed to appear in the GROUP BY rather than just the SELECT? Sorry if that's a dumb question. This is my first semester of this, I'm taking the course online and my instructor isn't much help. As a result I'm struggling to wrap my head around a lot of it. If you can explain that it would go a long way towards helping me in the future.

Once again... Thank you so so much!

Comment: The select list is just a visual, the group by clause is used to tell the database how you want to group values relative to aggregate functions used. In this case, you were displaying the year of each date, but grouping by the dates themselves, when summing. This didn't result in aggregation because you were retaining the full date. The select and group by are independent of one another, however all columns used in the select list, when aggregate functions are used, must also appear in the group by.

Answer (score 0):

You should extract the year of your date with the `year` function as follows:

```
SELECT YEAR(SalesOrder.OrderDate) AS year,
SUM(SalesOrder.OrderTotal) AS OrderTotal
FROM
SalesOrder
GROUP BY YEAR(SalesOrder.OrderDate);
```

Then, Your query will work as you're expecting.

Comment: Hey Carlos! First off, thanks for taking the time to help me out. I've taken your advice and put the YEAR function into the code and it's definitely a step in the right direction, but the years are still displaying separate order totals. I need it to add them all together per year.

Right now with the adjusted code I'm getting the following printout:

'code
year OrderTotal
2011 372.0000
2011 268.0000
2011 21782.5000
2012 871.5300
2012 1010.0000
2012 540.9000
2012 22.8300
2013 11.8500
2013 35.6000'

I need it to appear as one large total per year.

Thank you again for your help.

Comment: @sturmsworth  You have to group by the year column. That's why ;) And you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT YEAR(SalesOrder.OrderDate) AS year,
SUM(SalesOrder.OrderTotal) AS OrderTotal
FROM
SalesOrder
GROUP BY year(SalesOrder.OrderDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Year function to group by year of your date.

```
SELECT YEAR(SalesOrder.OrderDate) AS year,
SUM(SalesOrder.OrderTotal) AS OrderTotal
FROM
SalesOrder
GROUP BY YEAR(SalesOrder.OrderDate);
```